# Where is the source code for Android's entire BLE stack?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to understand how Android implements BLE at every level. Ideally, I'd like to trace the standard read, write, and connect commands all the way down the rabbit hole to the radio, if possible. Finding the top level Java source code is easy. But where can I find the rest?

Comment: Not clear if you've seen: https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list of Android repositories here:-

- https://android.googlesource.com/

Once you're there, just search for the keyword 'bluetooth' and you'll find a few different repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/Bluetooth/ is the active Bluetooth repository in Android.